# Add target to new link on toplinks

Tags: toplinks

I add new link to top links using

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks">
      <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
           <label>Blog</label>
           <url>/blog</url>
           <title>Blog</title>
           <prepare/>
           <urlParams/>
           <position>1</position>
      </action>
</block>
```

It works properly. 
I want to add `target="_blank"` to this link.
Is there any way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: where do we need to add this block, im using magento 1.9 default theme

Comment: Can we just add this if customer is logged in: <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>TEST</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>TEST</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>200</position></action>  below the Log Out Link

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `addLink` method accepts some extra parameters after position. take a look at `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links::addLink`.
So your xml could look like this:

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks">
  <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
       <label>Blog</label>
       <url>/blog</url>
       <title>Blog</title>
       <prepare/>
       <urlParams/>
       <position>1</position>
       <liParams />
       <aParams><![CDATA[target="_blank"]]></aParams>
  </action>
</block>
```

**[EDIT]**
If `prepare` is set to `true` then the url will be generated using

```
$this->getUrl('value of url tag', array with url params tag)
```

if it's not set then it will be generated using the url tag as it is.

`liParams` will be added to the `li` element that wraps the link.
Something like this:

```
<li class="some-class>...</li>
```

Same goes for `aParams`. They will be added to the `<a>` element.
In your case that will become

```
<a target="_blank"...>...</a>
```

Comment: could you explain what is the use of `liParams` and `prepare` tag

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR. I added an explanation to the answer. It was too long to fit in a comment.

Comment: great explanation..:)

Comment: Thank you. It works.
For further informations, if you set `aParams`, you have to set `liParams` as well, or at least you must have `liParams` tag. Otherwise, `aParams`'s value will be taken as `liParams`.
You can also use this for easier reading:
`<aParams><target>_blank</target></aParams>`

Answer (score 2):

```
<action method="setLinkTarget"><target>_blank</target></action>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this may be helpful to you I am using Magento CE 1.9.0.1 and this works fine for me try to add the link using below XML and you will get what you wants.

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks">
  <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
       <label>Blog</label>
       <url>/blog</url>
       <title>Blog</title>
       <prepare/>
       <urlParams/>
       <position>1</position>
       <li/>
       <a>target="_blank"</a>
  </action>
</block>
```

Answer (score 1):

On magento 2.0 this worked for me:

Blog/blog
       Blog Title
       
       2
       
       target="_blank"